# Type "OracleDbType.Int64" cannot be used in PL/SQL table parameter - devart dotConnect Express for Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, devart, dotconnect

I am working on a project where I want to use int64 as return type for the elements in an array returned by a PL/SQL procedure. The procedure is invoked using the dotConnect Express for Oracle data provider version 8.5.521 (downloaded from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotConnect.Express.for.Oracle/8.5.521)).

However, when I assign the `OracleParameter.ArrayLength` property, I get the following `ArgumentException`:

> Type "OracleDbType.Int64" cannot be used in PL/SQL table parameter.

The following snippet reproduces the error:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Using dotConnect.Express.for.Oracle.8.5.521 (from nuget)
            var op = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter(
                parameterName:"RESULT",
                dbType:Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDbType.Int64);

            op.IsNullable = true; // Ok
            op.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; // Ok

            // Throws ArgumentException
            // Type "OracleDbType.Int64" cannot be used in PL/SQL table parameter.
            op.ArrayLength = 3;

            Console.WriteLine(op.OracleDbType);
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the `dbType` parameter to `Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDbType.Integer` the `ArgumentException` is not thrown (however, I need the int64 data type, which is why that is not an option).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Short answer: try `Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDbType.Number` - this worked for sample test. Longer: [Devart docs for ArrayLength Property](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleParameter~ArrayLength.html). According to this you can only use _Number, Integer, Double, Float_ as number formats for PL/SQL structures. If this hint does not help please add more code, I don't see whole procedure call, parameters.